# Function behaviour on shell(ksh) script

Tags: shell, ksh, aix

Here are 2 different versions of a program:

**this**

Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

printmsg() {
        i=1
        print "hello function :)";
}
i=0;
echo I printed `printmsg`;
printmsg
echo $i
```

Output:

```
# ksh e
I printed hello function :)
hello function :)
1
```

**and**

Program:

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

printmsg() {
        i=1
        print "hello function :)";
}
i=0;
echo I printed `printmsg`;
echo $i
```

Output:

```
# ksh e
I printed hello function :)
0
```

The only difference between the above 2 programs is that `printmsg` is 2times in the above program while `printmsg` is called once in the below program.

My Doubt arises [here: To quote](http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-functions.html)

> Be warned: Functions act almost just like external scripts... except
>   that by default, all variables are SHARED between the same ksh
>   process! If you change a variable name inside a function.... that
>   variable's value will still be changed after you have left the
>   function!!

But we can **clearly** see in the 2nd program's output that the value of `i` remains unchanged. But we are sure that the function is called as the print statement gets the the output of the function and prints it. **So why is the output different in both?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use backticks (or $(...)), you execute it in a subshell.

That is, a new shell is started (which inherits from the current one) and then exists.

**Edit:** I checked [your link](http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-functions.html), if you read the bottom of it, the very last section, you'll see this explained.